# How to show custom horizontal scrollbar on mobile?

Tags: css, elementor, horizontal-scrolling

I've made a custom horizontal scrollbar in elementor with custom css, it works for desktop view but it doesn't work for mobile view, what am I missing? the following is the custom css that I use

```
.scroller-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 300px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
    border-radius: var(--whiskey-radius);
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: var(--whiskey-color);
    background-color: var(--whiskey-panel-background);
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}
.scroller-cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 800px;
    padding: 24px 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: auto;
}

.scroller-cards::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

.scroller-cards::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #0F2B4A;
    background: #0F2B4A;
    border-radius: 16px;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

[Here are the results](https://syahrul.webz.biz/horizontal-scrollbar/)

I'm still new to coding so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `flex-wrap` on screen below 1024px.

Reason: On screen below 1024px, cards moved on next line and content width of container is not greater than you container max width. That's why scroll is not applying

Comment: Make flex-wrap: unset on screen below  1024px.

Comment: Ok I got it, I already added the code below
@media (min-width: 1024px)
.elementor-section .elementor-container {
    flex-wrap: unset;
}

But it does'nt work

Comment: May be its overriding this css, make this important 

 @media (min-width: 1024px) .elementor-section .elementor-container { 
flex-wrap: unset !important;
 }

Comment: If its still not works, try

 .elementor-section .elementor-container { flex-wrap: unset !important; }

Comment: Its work, just forget to input the brace symbols. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, make upvote if this answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work on both Firefox desktop and Firefox mobile.

You're setting the scrollbar width to zero in this line:

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Later you're setting the scrollbar width here:

```
.scroller-cards::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

But because FF does not support `-webkit-scrollbar` your code doesn't work.

See [::-webkit-scrollbar on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar)